# Bookmarklet to append the content of a link to the current page

Tags: browser, bookmarklet

I haven't had any luck with AutoPager or AutoPagerize on a particular site (books24x7.com), so I was thinking of a more general solution - is there a general way to load the content of a link right at the end of the current page? That is, I'm on a webpage and do "something magical" and then click a link, then the page that was linked to loads at the bottom of the current page with AJAX magic.

(I'd also be interested in addons.)

Comment: It looks like the TiddlyWiki system has this sort of functionality for its internal links - I wonder if the same javascript could be used in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
javascript:void(function foo() {function openit(event){event.preventDefault(); $("#__").prop("src",event.target.href);};$("<iframe id='__' width='300' height='100'>").appendTo("body");$("body").on("click", "a", openit)  }() )
```